# How to require at compile time that a type parameter be a trait (and not a class or other type value)?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, type-bounds

I'm looking for some kind of upper bound on a generic parameter `T` that ensures that `T` is a trait.

```
class Foo
trait Bar

def f[A ??? IsATrait] = ???

// f[Foo] Won't compile
f[Bar] // this is fine
```

Comment: Not sure is if this is possible, what is your use case for this?

Comment: Please, read https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/2988 and https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/1352 to understand why "Is it possible" type questions are off-topic on [so] (and most of [se]).

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I'll reword it.

Comment: @Harald: I have a generic class with type parameter `A`. I want to a write a generic method with type parameter `B` that would only compile if the *run-time* type of `A` is a subtype of `B`. This is of course, possible if `A <: B` but it's also possible for some type `C extends A with B` if `B` is a `trait`, but otherwise it's not possible, e.g., if `A =:= Int` and `B =:= String`.

Comment: @Gal If that's the requirement then it's possible for any non-`AnyVal` classes, not just for traits (because of `null`). And for compound types. And probably for others...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You're right, but for now checking if it's a `trait` is good enough for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
typeOf[Bar].typeSymbol.asClass.isTrait // true
typeOf[Foo].typeSymbol.asClass.isTrait // false
```

---

At compile time

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait IsATrait[A]

object IsATrait { 
  implicit def materialize[A]: IsATrait[A] = macro impl[A]

  def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val tpA = weakTypeOf[A]
    if (tpA.typeSymbol.asClass.isTrait)
      q"new IsATrait[$tpA] {}"
    else c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$tpA is not a trait")
  }
}

def f[A: IsATrait] = ???

f[Bar] // compiles

f[Foo]
//Information: IsATrait.materialize is not a valid implicit value for IsATrait[Foo] because:
//             hasMatchingSymbol reported error: Foo is not a trait
//
//Error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type IsATrait[Foo]
//
//Error: not enough arguments for method f: (implicit evidence$1: IsATrait[Foo])Nothing.
//       Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
```

Comment: Not as "clean" as I would have hoped but apparently there's no first-class support for it. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to extend to check to also include Java `interface`s? I only found `isJava`, which of course also includes regular classes.

Comment: @Gal Not sure what you want. My code works for Java interfaces as well.

Comment: Nevermind, it was my mistake. I'm a macro newbie and forgot to properly import the macro in my use-site.

Answer (score -5):

> Is it possible to require at compile time that a type parameter is a trait (and not a class or other type value)?

No.